# Does having an extremely high number replication partners in Active Directory pose an issue in 2014?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, replication, scom

I'm consulting a network where they have 5 domain controllers in central location and a lot of Read Only controllers in additional locations. SCOM is shouting that there are extremely high number replication partners per each GC.

For example

- 81 instead of 40
- 58 instead of 40
- 65 instead of 40

While I could understand this could pose a problem in a slow networks couple of years back, and that SCOM is prepared for the worst case scenario (better to be safe then sorry) I was wondering if there's something more to the problem then just network and I should address this anyway by adding more central GC's to ease the load.

While I understand this is just a warning and I could ignore it, or I can change the monitoring level to not care if the limit isn't at least 100 but maybe there's more to it then I anticipate.